# First time use RSpec on Rails Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rspec-rails

this is the first time i use RSpec for unit testing in Rails Engine, i want to ask something that i dont understand how its work

this is my routes:

```
Community::Questions::Engine.routes.draw do
  resources :questions, path: '/', only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy, :update] do
    resources :answers, path: '/answers', only: [:index, :show, :create, :destroy, :update]
    resources :search, path: '/all', only: [:index]
  end
end
```

this is my controller

```
module Community::Questions
  class QuestionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[create update destroy]

    def index
      questions = Community::Question.last(5)

      render_json(questions)
    end
  end
end
```

and this is my spec test files

```
require "rails_helper"

RSpec.describe Community::Questions::QuestionsController, type: :controller do
  describe "GET index" do
    it "returns a 200" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end
  end
end
```

but ive got an error that i really have no idea

```
Failures:

  1) Community::Questions::QuestionsController GET index returns a 200
     Failure/Error: get :index
     
     ActionController::UrlGenerationError:
       No route matches {:action=>"index", :controller=>"community/questions/questions"}
     # ./spec/community/questions_controller_spec.rb:6:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 0.02578 seconds (files took 1.31 seconds to load)
1 example, 1 failure

Failed examples:

rspec ./spec/community/questions_controller_spec.rb:5 # Community::Questions::QuestionsController GET index returns a 200
```

does anyone here know where is my fault? and know how to fix my unit test please? an insight really helpful, thankyou so much :)

Comment: When you run `rake routes`, do you see route that matches what the test is looking for (the part after "No route matches: ")?

Comment: this is probably a zeitwerk problem. When you namespace a controller in this way, zeitwerk has very specific requirements about where it expects to find the `questions_controller.rb` file. I think it should be in the engine, in app/controllers/community/questions/questions_controller.rb.